# Tangent planes and differentiable function

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

The question below is from *Anton's "Calculus" 5th edition*. Couldn't find a solution online and there's no solution in the book.

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function and a surface $z=x\cdot f(\frac{x}{y})$.
>   Prove that all tangent plane to the surface share a common point".

EDIT: question misunderstood, solution posted as answer for future reference.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the problem. I don't think it merely wants you to show that each pair of planes has an intersection point. I think you are supposed to show that there is a point somewhere in the space such that every single plane passes through that particular point.

Comment: It might help to write out what $F(x,y,z)$ is in terms of $x,y,z,$ $f(x/y),$ and $f'(x/y)$.

Comment: I have indeed misunderstood the problem, thanks for the comment.

Comment: You should write your solution up as an answer instead of adding it to the question.

Comment: Your solution looks good. If you made an answer from it (it _is_ permitted to answer your own question!) you could accept it. (But you might want to wait another day or so, to invite further comment on it before you mark this question as settled.)

Comment: Didn't know that was an option, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the question, here's a solution...

To prove the claim we need to show a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^3$ so that every plane tangent to the given surface passes through that point.

Derive the normal vector to the surface at some point $p=(a,b,c)$ using the gradient of the surface $F(x,y,z)=x\cdot f(x/y)-z$.

The gradient at $p$ is: $$\nabla F(a,b,c)=(f(\frac{a}{b})+\frac{a}{b}f'(\frac{a}{b}),-\frac{a^2}{b^2}f'(\frac{a}{b}),-1)$$ so the tangent plane is by $\langle \nabla F(p),\bar{x}-p\rangle $: $$(f(\frac{a}{b})+\frac{a}{b}f'(\frac{a}{b}))(x-a)-\frac{a^2}{b^2}f'(\frac{a}{b})(y-b)-(z-c)=0$$ after substituting $c=a\cdot f(\frac{a}{b})$, by the definition of the surface, we can rearrange the terms of the plane and get the equation: $$(f(\frac{a}{b})+\frac{a}{b}f'(\frac{a}{b}))x-\frac{a^2}{b^2}f'(\frac{a}{b})y-z=0$$ which means that the plane passes through the origin $(0,0,0)$, thus showing that the plane tangent to every point on the surface passes through a common point.