# Find the common point of the all the tangent planes.

Tags: calculus, tangent-spaces

Let $f(t)$ be a differntiable function $\forall t $ , let $z$ be a surface such that $z=xf(\frac{x}{y}),y\neq 0$.

Find the common point of the all the tangent planes.

My attempt:

Denote $g(x,y):=xf(\frac{x}{y}),y\neq 0$.

I can find the tangent surface in $(x_0,y_0)$ using theorem $z=g(x_0,y_0)+\frac{dg}{dx}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{dg}{dy}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0).$

Now, $(x_0,y_0)=(t,y_0)$

$z=tf(\frac{t}{y_0})+(f(\frac{t}{y_0})+tf(\frac{t}{y_0})\frac{1}{y_0})(x-t)+tf(-\frac{t}{y_0^2})(y-y_0)$

How to find the common point of all tangent planes ?

Comment: Two non parallel planes define a line. Two intersecting non parallel lines define a point. So if you take four planes you either get them non intersecting (no common point then) or intersecting at some point. In the latter case you’d just need to show that the latter belong to all other planes. In case tangent planes are parallel, do you know what that means?

Comment: Similar question here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273660/tangent-planes-and-differentiable-function